# Fixar o tamanho de propriedade do tipo array

Tags: c#

Tenho uma propriedade que é do tipo array. Esse array deve ter de duas dimensões sendo 7 linhas e 4 colunas, ou seja, ***AnyType[7,4]***, código:

```
public class WorkingDays
{
    public TimeSpan[,] Times { get; set; }

}
```

Como eu faço para fixar um tamanho, obrigando que seja passado um array de 7x4, ou seja ***[7,4]***?
Eu sei que é possível fazer validações no ***set*** mas eu penso em algo como no C onde você já define o tamanho na declaração do tipo.

Comment: Não é possível. Você pode validar no método `set` ou pode deixar a instância pronta e só deixar o "usuário" manipular esta matriz `public TimeSpan[,] Times { get; } => new TimeSpan[7, 4];`.

Comment: :(, nesse caso então não me resta outra alternativa a não ser validar no `set` ?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Eu tava editando o comentário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não é possível.

Como você pretende que está propriedade seja "*setada*" pelo consumidor do código, a melhor alternativa seria validar no método `set` da propriedade

```
using System;

public class WorkingDays
{
    private TimeSpan[,] _times;

    public TimeSpan[,] Times
    {
        get { return _times; }
        set
        {
            if (value.GetLength(0) != 7 || value.GetLength(1) != 4)
                throw new Exception("Tamanho de matriz inválido");
            _times = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var wd = new WorkingDays();
        try 
        {
            wd.Times = new TimeSpan[8, 4];
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //Só pra não quebrar o exemplo
        }

        wd.Times = new TimeSpan[7, 4];
    }
}
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NeYsv4)**</sup>

---

A título de curiosidade, é possível definir *arrays* com tamanho fixo em contextos *unsafe*. Porém, além de altamente não recomendável, não é possível fazer isso com *arrays* multidimensionais, em classes (só vale pra *struct*) e que contenham tipos fora dos pré-definidos.

Um exemplo:

```
void Main()
{
    var wd = new UWorkingDays();

    unsafe{
        Console.WriteLine(wd.Times[0]);
    }
}

public unsafe struct UWorkingDays
{   
    public fixed int Times[7];
}
```